# How to retrieve all instances of a contract from a node using Web3.js with the ABI of the contract?

Tags: web3js, dapp-development

I am new to Solidity and Web3.js. I created a contract and tested it using Remix. 
With Web3.js, I am able to get the contract instance if I know the address and query it and print the results on a web page.

But I want to query and get all the instances of a type of contract that is already created and list it on my HTML page. For this, I assume that I have to get the addresses of these instances. I will appreciate if anybody can provide pointers on how to go about doing this.

If this is not possible, I want to be able to create instances of contract from Web3.js without having to create it in Remix. Pointers for that will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a registry pattern, where each new instance add itself to a registry contract. Where you can query already deployed contracts.

Or a factory pattern where the factory creates each contract and keeps a list of deployed contracts.

Comment: Thank you @Ismael. With the Registry pattern, I will still have to keep track of the address of that one contract in an external store. Is there a way to query the BlockChain to get all contracts of a certain type or based on some search criteria like you would do with SQL?